# Why do I need to install Java Cryptography Extension each time java updates?

Tags: java, jce

Each time my system updates java, and then nothing runs because it was a new Java Cryptography Extension installed. Is this normal behaviour or something wrong with my settings.

Why does new version needs to be manually installed each time java updates? It's getting very annoying

Comment: That's not normal. Or are you talking about the full strength JCE licence? You'll have to thank your southern neighbours for that idiocy.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, the licence. ...Oh those rascals... Always ruin it for everyone else

Comment: You don't even know what I'm referring to, do you?

Comment: @Kayaman this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Comment: Yes, and that's because America decided that cryptography is a "weapon" and its exports need to be controlled. But that licence is the only thing I can think of causing problems (related to JCE) when updating Java.

Comment: Good question. It's driving me nuts.